# Reassign Data Frame Values using apply

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, assign

I would like to use apply to re-assign values in a matrix or data frame of data.  specifically I try to replace negative values in each row with the same values normalized by the sum of negative values in the row.
I try to replace the positive values the same way.

Create some Data

```
init <- runif(length(n), min = -1, max = 1)
    init[which(init < 0)] <- init[which(init < 0)]/-sum(init[which(init < 0)])
    init[which(init > 0)] <- init[which(init > 0)]/sum(init[which(init > 0)])


sd = c(.16, .18, .05,.07,.23,.26,.01)/sqrt(365)
increment <- sapply(sd, function(x) rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = x)) * runif(length(n), min = -1, max = 1)
```

Create a data frame

```
series <- data.frame(apply(increment + 1, 2, function(x) cumprod(x)) * init)
```

Re-assign the values in each row

```
series <- apply(series, 1, function(x) {
  x[which(x < 0)] <- x[which(x < 0)]/-sum(x[which(x < 0)])
  x[which(x > 0)] <- x[which(x > 0)]/sum(x[which(x > 0)])
  return(x)
})
```

I intend to get a data frame of the same dimensions as before the replacement, but that is not the case.  It is challenging my understanding of how apply works.

thanks.

Comment: I think it's just transposed from what you want, yes? It's returning 7 rows and 10 columns, which is what the help (under Value) describes, whereas your original data is 10 rows and 7 columns.

Comment: Is there a reason you do not keep it as a `matrix`? It's faster, more memory-efficient, and `apply` is perfect for it. Otherwise, using `apply` with a `data.frame` is almost always wrong, in that it is less efficient, causes unnecessary conversion (`frame <--> matrix`) or coercion (`numeric <--> character` or at least `integer <--> numeric`), and cause some headache with regards to its default tranposition.